# Should I treat inverse trigonometric functions differently based on the angle value?

Tags: math

When I'm looking into Google's previous cardboard sdk ([decompiled one on Github](https://github.com/raasun/cardboard)), there is a [function](https://github.com/raasun/cardboard/blob/master/src/com/google/vrtoolkit/cardboard/sensors/internal/So3Util.java#L106-L151) extracts rotation axis and angle from a [rodrigues' rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula). The math is straightforward and explained in detail [here](http://electroncastle.com/wp/?p=416).

[image: math]

What is confusing me is that the author who wrote this [code](https://github.com/raasun/cardboard/blob/master/src/com/google/vrtoolkit/cardboard/sensors/internal/So3Util.java#L106-L151) divided the calculation into three cases ( cosθ > sqrt(1/2) ; cosθ < -sqrt(1/2) ; -sqrt(1/2) ≤ cosθ ≤ sqrt(1/2) ). But in fact the first case can be applied generally except for the case where θ = 0

Can anyone figure out why the author did this? is that about accuracy or performance? or is there something fatal I've missed

Comment: The second case is cosθ > -sqrt(1/2) and the third is sqrt(1/2) ≤ abs(cosθ).    Anyway, another possible explanation is getting θ in the correct quadrant.   Without knowing what all the other variables in that code do, it is not possible to answer definitively.

Answer (score 0):

The Rodrigues formula is

```
     R = I + sin(th)*K + (1-cos(th))*K²
```

where `K` is the anti-symmetric matrix realizing the cross product with `k=(kx,ky,kz)` (`k=n` in the question). For its square one also has the formula `K²=k*k^T-I` so that an alternative form is

```
    R = cos(th)*I+sin(th)*K+(1-cos(th))*(k*k^T).
```

---

The subdivision of the angle range serves to work around the usual limitations of `asin` and `acos` for arguments that are close to `+1` or `-1`. This could have been avoided by computing for all cases

```
    angle = Math.atan2(sinAngleAbs, cosAngle);
```

(*Esp. since in most implementations, the identities `asin(x)=atan2(x,sqrt(1-x*x))` and `acos(x)=atan2(sqrt(1-x*x),x)` are used, as the x86 FPU provides `FPATAN` as the only inverse trig. function.*)

---

One source of cancellation errors is in computing the anti-symmetric part of `R`,

```
    (R-R^T)/2 = sin(th)*K
```

The non-diagonal entries have the form

```
    R(1,2)=-sin(th)*kz + (1-cos(th))*kx*ky
          =2*sin(th/2)*( -cos(th/2)*kz + sin(th/2)*kx*ky ), …
```

If `sin(th)` is small and `cos(th)` close to `-1`, that is, the angle `th` is close to `pi`, and, in this case, `sin(th)*kz` is small against `kx*ky` then cancellation errors occur in `R-R^T` in this component. And similarly if any of the other components is that small in one of the other components. That is why the entries in that case are better determined from

```
(R+R^T)/2 = I + (1-cos(th))*K²
          = cos(th)*I + (1-cos(th))*(k*k^T)
```

by selecting in `(1-cos(th))*k*k^T` the column with the largest multiplier among `kx,ky,kz`.